# Background post submit cancels all active ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax

My app does a massive amount of ajax calls. Somewhere in the middle I'm making a form submit to download a file without having to refresh the page. This form submit cancels all active ajax calls. Anyone has any experience with it? How can I make the submit without having my ajax calls cancelled?

I've tried making the post inside an iFrame but it still cancels the calls. Posting to a new target doesn't cancel but it's not an option due to usability issues (it looks bad)

The sequence is the following (for simplification of the example let's consider that the server returns the ajax calls in sequence):

```
Call ajax1
Call ajax2
Call ajax3
Call ajax4

Ajax 1 returns
Ajax 2 returns
Form submit (POST) on the background to download a file
Ajax 3 cancelled by browser
Ajax 4 cancelled by browser
```